# Como obtener la peticion de la API al momento de entrar a la pagina | vite.config

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, vite

Quiero que mi pagina hecha con React, al entrar a la raíz, haga una petición a una api que esta en el vite.config, como se podría agarrar la respuesta de la api para poder usarla.

Server en Node

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const { headers } = req
    console.log('Headers', headers) //Para ver que si se hizo la conexión
    res.json(true)
})
```

vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Si hace la petición pero te muestra la respuesta en pantalla.